# Angular6 and angular-material version

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6

I am currently on angular version 6.1.10 and I recently downloaded the latest version of /material and /cdk. My question is, will version 8.0.0 of /material be compatible with version 6.1.10 of Angular??

Comment: I am using 7 with no material issues.

Comment: material drag n drop wont work with 6 (you could use dragula or similar instead) - otherwise i'm not aware of any material limitations, but I would recommend a small & quick sandbox/test-app where you add the mat-components to see if they behave as intended (reactive and tempate-driven)..

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're mixing two topics:

- Every major release can have some breaking changes, but most of the API (components, CSS, methods) will be compatible, some parts may not.
- The `cdk` and `material` packages needs to work with the same versions of the `core`, you can't upgrade one and leave the other behind, they will always have correlated releases to be used together.

Happy ng-coding!